# How to Create Function Parameters that do not require input Powershell

Tags: powershell, parameters

I was writing a simple function to test something  and wanted to know if it is possible to create a parameters that do not require arguments but can be specified to run a particular action.  I searched but dont see anyone using this.  Like for instance the -Recurse paramater in get-childitem.  It doesnt require arguments but when you specify it always implies recursive searching.  Is there a way to do it in a function?  I have tried [AllowNull()], [AllowEmptyString()] with the parameter but when i test it i get an error for no argument.

Comment: the `-Recurse` parameter is a `switch parameter`. they default to `$False` and become `$True` when you use the switch. you can test for that inside the function and act on the result. [*grin*]

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for a [`SwitchParameter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.switchparameter?view=pscore-6.2.0)!

There's a nifty `[switch]` type accelerator for it, so you can implement your own such parameter like this:

```
function Test-SwitchParam
{
  param(
    [switch]$MySwitch
  )

  if($MySwitch.IsPresent){
    Write-Host "MySwitch was specified!"
  }
}
```

Comment: Cool thanks, ive seen it but never used it so i overlooked it.